# Computing a map between two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

What I want is a little difficult to explain. So I try to it with an example.

I have 2 lists, each of which has $(n-1)^2$ elements. Each element is an integer between 0 and $n-1$, inclusive.

For example for $n=4$:

```
L1 = {1,2,3,2,0,2,3,2,1}
L2 = {2,3,0,3,0,1,0,1,2}
```

From these lists I want to compute possible elements of `L2` that correspond to an 
element of `L1`. The result is an **ordered** list with $n$ elements:

```
{{0},{2},{1,3},{0}}
```

This means:

- If you select `0` from `L1`, the corresponding elements in `L2` are `{0}`.
- If you select `1` from `L1`, the corresponding elements in `L2` are
  `{2}`.
- If you select `2` from `L1`, the corresponding elements in `L2` are `{1,3}`.
- If you select `3` from `L1`, the corresponding elements in `L2` are `{0}`.

Comment: for `n=3` max element must be 2? In your exmaple `L1:={1,2,3,2,0,2,3,2,1}` with `n=3`max element is 3.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the typo.

Comment: Does `L1` always contains whole range 0 to n-1?

Comment: Good question! No, it does not. Some of the result elements could very well be empty: `{}`. In particular, for $n$ a large prime, there could be many empty sets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
GatherBy[Union@Transpose@{L1, L2}, First][[;; , ;; , 2]]
```

Comment: Forget a day or 2. Good enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

```
Sort@Thread[L1 -> L2] ~Merge~ Union // Values
```

> ```
> {{0}, {2}, {1, 3}, {0}}
> ```

After reading Kuba's answer I realize this could also be written:

```
Values @ Merge[Union @ Thread[L1 -> L2], # &]
```

Comment: This is a nice representation of the problem, especially (imo) without the `Values`, in which it actually is a mapping instead of the OP's stripped down representation of one. (+1)

Answer (score 6):

With MMA10 this can be done by this code:

```
DeleteDuplicates /@ GroupBy[Transpose@{L1, L2}, First -> Last]
(*<|1 -> {2}, 2 -> {3, 1}, 3 -> {0}, 0 -> {0}|>*)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
n = 4;
AdjacencyMatrix[Graph[Range[0, n - 1], Thread@DirectedEdge[L1, L2]]]["AdjacencyLists"] - 1
(* {{0}, {2}, {1, 3}, {0}} *)
```

Faster than I thought it would be, but not as fast as Kuba's when `L1` and `L2` are packed arrays.

The graph itself is a nice representation of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) for this purpose:

```
r = Union /@ Nearest[L1 -> L2, Range[0, 3]]
```

> {{0}, {2}, {1, 3}, {0}}

A timing comparison with @Kuba's answer:

```
L1 = RandomInteger[1000,10^6];
L2 = RandomInteger[1000,10^6];

r1 = GatherBy[Union @ Transpose@{L1,L2}, First][[;; , ;; , 2]]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Union /@ Nearest[L1 -> L2, Range[0, 1000]]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1===r2
```

> {0.299931, Null}
>
> {0.191812, Null}
>
> True

So, a little bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
Union[Pick[L2, L1, #]] & /@ Range[0, 3]
```

> {{0}, {2}, {1, 3}, {0}}

Comment: A very underrated answer - I would replace `Range[0, 3]` with `Union[L2]` for more generality.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
Values[KeySort[Merge[Thread[L1 -> L2], Union]]]
```

Alternatively `DeleteDuplicates` could be used.

Answer (score 1):

Using the 3rd argument of `GroupBy`:

```
GroupBy[Transpose[{L1, L2}], First -> Last, Union] // Dataset
```

[image]